# Get WOEID in Android

Tags: java, android, api, rss, yahoo-api

I'm developing an app and one of the features I want to include is being able to get the users location and convert it to a WOEID value and then get the weather data from the Yahoo Weather RSS feed. Here's the documentation that states the requirement for the WOEID value:
http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the WOEID by using the [Yahoo! PlaceFinder API](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/). First you need to request an API key, then you can send your request like this:

```
http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?q=[search query]&appid=[yourappidhere]
```

You will get this as a response:

```
<ResultSet xmlns:ns1="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" version="2.0" xml:lang="en-US">
<Error>0</Error>
<ErrorMessage>No error</ErrorMessage>
<Locale>en-US</Locale>
<Found>1</Found>
<Quality>85</Quality>
<Result>
<quality>85</quality>
<latitude>38.898708</latitude>
<longitude>-77.036369</longitude>
<offsetlat>38.89719</offsetlat>
<offsetlon>-77.036537</offsetlon>
<radius>400</radius>
<name/>
<line1>1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW</line1>
<line2>Washington, DC 20500-0005</line2>
<line3/>
<line4>United States</line4>
<house>1600</house>
<street>Pennsylvania Ave NW</street>
<xstreet/>
<unittype/>
<unit/>
<postal>20500-0005</postal>
<neighborhood/>
<city>Washington</city>
<county>District of Columbia</county>
<state>District of Columbia</state>
<country>United States</country>
<countrycode>US</countrycode>
<statecode>DC</statecode>
<countycode>DC</countycode>
<uzip>20500</uzip>
<hash>4216F67AA1A143E9</hash>
<woeid>12766118</woeid> // This is what you need
<woetype>11</woetype>
</Result>
</ResultSet>
```

You can parse the response for the `<woeid>` tag.

**Edit:**
If you have an EditText and you want to get the weather based on the city you get from his input then you'll have to do this:

```
String searchQuery = Uri.encode(myEditText.getText().toString());
```

Now you'll have your search query. So e.g if the user types in:

> Hamburg Germany

then this will convert it to:

> Hamburg_Germany

Comment: This is an XML response, you can parse it using an XML parser(DOM, SAX or pullparser)

Comment: What goes in [search query]?